# How to get my current ID in CursorAdapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a ListView, which is populated by a CursorAdapter. Each item in ListView has a spinner, a button and a checkbox. I need to update values in database when the user selects something in spinner, ticks the checkbox or pushes the button. The problem is, that I don't know how to access the ID for database entry to update it. Every time something in any of list items is changed, it updates values for the last list item.

I've tried to use *setTag()* and *getTag()* for my three views, but when getTag() is called in a listener, I get a *null* value. How I get the ID for my current list item?

UPDATE: Okay, I'm getting closer to solving the case. My problem now is that I don't know how to properly set and get a tag to a spinner. I tried to get tag from parent AdapterView, but that's not it.

```
public class DoorSelectorCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private ProjectsDBHelper mDbHelper;
    Button bDelete;
    Spinner spDoor;
    TextView tvDoorName;
    CheckBox cbAdded;
    String doorID;
    long currentID, wallID;
    Intent mIntent;
    public DoorSelectorCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, Intent intent) {

        super(context, cursor, 0);
        final String LOG_TAG = DoorSelectorCursorAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "DoorSelectorCursorAdapter инициализирован");
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.selector_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    // The bindView method is used to bind all data to a given view
    // such as setting the text on a TextView.
    @Override
    public void bindView(final View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        final String LOG_TAG = DoorSelectorCursorAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "вызван BindView");

        currentID = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.WallDoorEntry.COLUMN_WALLDOOR_ID));
        wallID = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.WallDoorEntry.COLUMN_WALLDOOR_IDWALL_FK));
        spDoor = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item);
        tvDoorName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selector_itemName);
        cbAdded = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.selector_checkbox);
        bDelete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.selector_button_delete);
        spDoor.setTag(currentID);
        cbAdded.setTag(currentID);
        bDelete.setTag(currentID);

        //res[0] = (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.WallDoorEntry.COLUMN_WALLDOOR_IDDOOR_FK)) - 1);
//        final long[] iCurrentSelection = new long[1];
//        iCurrentSelection[0] = spDoor.getSelectedItemPosition();
        int currentPosition = cursor.getPosition();
        tvDoorName.setText("Дверь " + (currentPosition + 1));

        if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.WallDoorEntry.COLUMN_WALLDOOR_EXISTS)) == 1){
            cbAdded.setChecked(true);
        } else if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.WallDoorEntry.COLUMN_WALLDOOR_EXISTS)) == 0) {
            cbAdded.setChecked(false);
        }

        final Cursor doorCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(DataContract.DoorEntry.CONTENT_URI, null, null,  null, null);
        if (doorCursor.getCount() > 0){
            DoorCursorAdapter doorAdapter = new DoorCursorAdapter(context, doorCursor);
            spDoor.setAdapter(doorAdapter);
        }
        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.WallDoorEntry.COLUMN_WALLDOOR_IDDOOR_FK)) != null){
            spDoor.setSelection(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.WallDoorEntry.COLUMN_WALLDOOR_IDDOOR_FK)) - 1);
        }

        spDoor.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//                if (res[0] == id){

//                }
//                else {
//                    spDoor.setSelection(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.WallDoorEntry.COLUMN_WALLDOOR_IDDOOR_FK)) - 1);
//                }
//                if (iCurrentSelection[0] != id){
//                    // Your code here
                int intID = (Integer) view.getTag();
                    doorID = String.valueOf(id);
                    updateEntry(intID);
//                }
//                iCurrentSelection[0] = id;
        }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
        cbAdded.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           int intID = (Integer) view.getTag();
                                           updateEntry(intID);
                                       }
                                   });
//                cbAdded.setOnClickListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
//                                               @Override
//                                               public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
//                                                   updateEntry();
//                                               }
//                                           }
//        );

        bDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                deleteEntry(cursor, arg0.getTag());
            }
        });

    }

    private void deleteEntry(Cursor cursor, Object tag) {
            mContext.getContentResolver().delete(DataContract.WallDoorEntry.CONTENT_URI, DataContract.WallDoorEntry.COLUMN_WALLDOOR_ID + " LIKE " + tag, null);
//            Cursor newCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(DataContract.WallDoorEntry.CONTENT_URI, null,DataContract.WallDoorEntry.COLUMN_WALLDOOR_IDWALL_FK + " LIKE " + wallID, null, null);
//            super.swapCursor(newCursor);
    }

    private void updateEntry(int tagID) {
        ContentValues entryValues = new ContentValues();
        entryValues.put(DataContract.WallDoorEntry.COLUMN_WALLDOOR_IDDOOR_FK, doorID);
        int checked = 0;
        if (cbAdded.isChecked() == true){
            checked = 1;
        }
        entryValues.put(DataContract.WallDoorEntry.COLUMN_WALLDOOR_EXISTS, checked);

        int numOfUpdatedEntries = mContext.getContentResolver().update(DataContract.WallDoorEntry.CONTENT_URI, entryValues,
                DataContract.WallDoorEntry.COLUMN_WALLDOOR_ID + " LIKE " + tagID, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: it might not working because You are working on returned cursor variable. Take all values what You need from the cursor and save to local variables. Work on that variables otherwise You might see mixed values on visible views. And to get cursor id You call: `cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))`

Comment: Okay, I'm getting closer to solving the case. My problem now is that I don't know how to properly set and get a tag to a spinner. I tried to get tag from parent AdapterView, but that's not it.

Comment: Update and cleanup Your code, please. If You found solution for current problem - mark it as solved or add own. Keep in mind 1 problem - 1 solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save state of bound items in some `Collection` in `Adapter`.

```
final Map<Integer, Integer> mBoundItems = new HashMap<>();
```

Save state, once item binding. You can use any object, as key, to access you IDs. In this example, you can use your known Key for the Item.

```
final int key = someKnownKeyForItem();
mBoundItems.put(key, currentID);
```

Then whenever you need data from based on Click of `Views` and known for this position Key, or any other condition.

```
final int key = someKnownKeyForThisItem();
final int id = mBoundItems.get(key);
```

Comment: `CursorAdapter` provides all needed information to achive author's problem. You forget we are working on the list's views - not static views. Your solution won't work after scroll.

Comment: @deadfish I won't work with Recycler, where all views recyclers. Actually, I it's ex. only, to show, how save state, of something which is bound. And it's useful fo Cursor Adapter, where items binding from cursor,, and you don't have access for whole collection.

Comment: I am still sure Your solution is not right. Why would You use map with `view.hashCode` and `currentId` in adapter? You are passing cursor to `bindView`, it can give You current row's id. Besides we are working on single view with click listener. There is no need to store all views' ids in adapter.

Comment: @deadfish Omg, I see it's hard to see just example here.

Comment: @deadfish I updated question, so you can live with this.

Comment: I know how Your code works, Your solution just doesn't fit for current author's problem.